# Strings form list to function

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am using Mathematica version 5.2.  I need to split it to function, and make a result..
    I've created this monster:

```
mx = {};
arg = {};
fun = {}; 
x =. 
y =.
```

here are lists and arguments

```
switchfunction2[y_] := Switch[y,
  1, AppendTo[fun, Cos[Random[Integer, {1, 10}]]],
  2, AppendTo[fun, Sin[Random[Integer, {1, 10}]]],
  3, AppendTo[fun, Tan[Random[Integer, {1, 10}]]],
  4, AppendTo[fun, Csc[Random[Integer, {1, 10}]]],
  5, AppendTo[fun, Sec[Random[Integer, {1, 10}]]],
  6, AppendTo[fun, Cot[Random[Integer, {1, 10}]]]
]
```

and random functions

```
Do[AppendTo[mx, Random[Integer, {1, 10}]], {i, 2}] 

mx[[1]] " has been chosed"
mx[[2]] "argumments "
Do[AppendTo[arg, Random[Integer, {1, 5}]], {i, mx[[2]]}] 
arg
Do[switchfunction2 /@ {arg[[i]]}, {i, mx[[2]]}]
fun
```

I want to obtain `f[z_]:=fun[[1]]+fun[[2]]...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, I would do something like

```
mx = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 2];
arg = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, mx[[2]]];

switch[y_] := Module[{f},
  f = Switch[y, 1, Cos, 2, Sin, 3, Tan, 4, Csc, 5, Sec, 6, Cot];
  f[RandomInteger[{1, 10}]]]

fun = switch /@ arg;

Total[fun]
```

Or without using a switch function:

```
mx = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 2]
flist = RandomChoice[{Cos, Sin, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot}, mx[[2]]];

fun = #[RandomInteger[{1, 10}]] & /@ flist;
Total[fun]
```

**Edit**

Here's a version that should work in Mathematica 5.2.

```
mx = Table[Random[Integer, {1, 10}], {2}];
arg = Table[Random[Integer, {1, 5}], {mx[[2]]}];

switch[y_] := Module[{f}, 
  f = Switch[y, 1, Cos, 2, Sin, 3, Tan, 4, Csc, 5, Sec, 6, Cot];
  f[Random[Integer, {1, 10}]]]

fun = switch /@ arg;

Total[fun]
```

To make a function out of this you could wrap everything in a `Module`, e.g.

```
f := Module[{mx, arg, switch},
  mx = Random[Integer, {1, 10}];
  arg = Table[Random[Integer, {1, 5}], {mx}];
  switch[y_] := Module[{f}, 
    f = Switch[y, 1, Cos, 2, Sin, 3, Tan, 4, Csc, 5, Sec, 6, Cot];
    f[Random[Integer, {1, 10}]]];
  Total[switch /@ arg]]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but I obtained this code:  <pre> **code'RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 2]'  and '2[RandomInteger[{1, 10}]] + {Cos, Sin, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot}[RandomInteger[{1, 
      10}]]** I need to get a function

Comment: _I Need to get for example_ **f1:=Cos(10)+ Sin(3)+Tan(4)...etc**

Comment: Both versions produce something like `Cot[4] + Csc[1] + Tan[5] ...` on my computer. It looks like `RandomChoice` didn't resolve properly in your case (flist should have been something like `{Tan, Sin, ...}`) but I don't know how that could have happened.

Comment: That would explain it. `RandomInteger` and `RandomChoice` were introduced in version 6. I'll add a version that should work in mathematica 5.2.

Comment: I'd to make other operations- not only adding elements...

Something like fun1*fun2-fun3+fun4+fun5...etc